# No me entra en el IF

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

Buenas tengo un jsp que pasa datos a mi servlet con ajax.

Este es mi Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dni = "00000r";

  $.post('actionServlet', {
    }, function(responseText) {
        num: "1"
        $('#datos').html(responseText);
    });

  $("#mostrar").click(function(){
      $.post('actionServlet', {
            num: "2",
            dni: dni
        }, function(responseText) {
            $('#datos').html(responseText);
        });

  });
});
```

y este mi java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType( "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" );
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    // Obtengo los datos de la peticion
    String numero = request.getParameter("num");
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");

    System.out.println(numero+" "+numero.getClass());

    if(numero == "1"){
        out.println("Prueba numero 1");
    }

    if(numero == "2"){
        out.println("Ha funcionado");
    }
}
```

Al pasar los datos no me hace los if en el java.
¿Alguna solución? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Para comparar strings utiliza equals en vez de == Se haría numero.Equals("1")

Comment: vale muchas gracias , me funciono :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Java no puede comparar objetos con == debes usar el método .equals

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {     
 response.setContentType( "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" );
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

 // Obtengo los datos de la peticion
 String numero = request.getParameter("num");
 String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");

 System.out.println(numero+" "+numero.getClass());

 if(numero.equals("1")){
     out.println("Prueba numero 1");
 }

 if(numero.equals("2")){
     out.println("Ha funcionado");
 } 
}
```

Comment: No solo Strings; esto es para cualquier objeto.

Comment: si, toda la razón ... rectificado